# How to replace only the text of this element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a kind of simple search engine, where
the user enters a string and if it's equal to the text inside
an element, that portion of text must be highlighted some way.

This is the html:

```
 <input type="text">
 <input type="button" value="Change text"><br>
 <a href="#">Click here to get more info!</a>
```

this is the css:

```
.smallcaps{
  color:red;
}
```

and this is the jquery function that makes the search and replace:

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function(){
  var textValue = $("input[type=text]").val();
  $("a").html(function(_, html) {
    return  html.replace(new RegExp(textValue,"ig"), '<span class="smallcaps">'+textValue+'</span>');
  });
});
```

This is an example of how it looks like:

[image]

Everything works fine, until the search string is equals to the name of a node element, so for example if the search string is **a**, the html will be broken.

[image]

How can I avoid the replace of the html itself?. I just want to work over the text.

This is the codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mefkb

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to only highlight the last search and not store the ones from before.

With this assumption, you can store the old value if it is the first call and use the stored value in the calls afterwards:

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function(){
    // Escape the html of the input to be able to search for < or >
    var textValue = $('<div/>').text($("input[type=text]").val()).html();
    if(textValue === '') return;

    $("a").html(function(_, html) {
        var old = $(this).data('content');
        if(!old) {
            old = html;
            $(this).data('content', old);
        }
        var replacer = function(match) {
            return match.replace(new RegExp(textValue, "ig"), '<span class="smallcaps">'+textValue+'</span>');
        };

        if(/[<>]/.test(old)) {
            return old.replace(/^[^<>]*</gi, replacer).replace(/>[^<>]*</gi, replacer).replace(/>[^<>]*$/gi, replacer);
        }
        return replacer(old);
    });
});
```

Also i fixed two bugs I found when testing:

1. if you search for an empty string, everything is broken.
2. If you search for html characters like < or > nothing is found as in the text they are converted to &lt; or &gt;.

One thing is not solved, as it is not possible to easily implement it without destroying the subelement structure: It is not possible to search in different subelements, as you have to remove the tags, search then and insert the tags at the right position afterwards.

Working fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KlxEB

Comment: thanks Tobbe, I'll try I'll try this in a couple of hours, but what would be a fix in case the anchor contains other elements?

Comment: Updated the code to solve this problem. Also fixed two bugs I found.

Answer (score 1):

### [Updated Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fvIec)

A workaround would be to restore `<a>` to original text, instead of complicating the regex.

Your problem is `a` form the `<span>` tag is getting replaced.

```
var init = $("a").text();    //save initial value
$("input[type='button']").click(function(){
    $('a').text(init);       //replace with initial value
    var textValue = $("input[type=text]").val();
    $("a").html(function(_, html) { 
         return  html.replace(new RegExp(textValue,"ig"), '<span class="smallcaps">'+textValue+'</span>');
    });
});
```